# Magento 2 Get Currency Symbol from Currency Code

Tags: magento2, php, currency

I have below code

```
$currencyManager        = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->getResource(); 
echo $currencySymbol    = $currencyManager->getCurrencyCodeFromToCurrency('USD');
```

It gives fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Currency::getCurrencyCodeFromToCurrency()

Can anybody guide me to get Currency Symbol from Currency Code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
$currency = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currencyCode);
$currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```

It would be beter to use `CurrencyRepository` but it's not yet implemented in Magento 2.

Answer (score 7):

We can do this using Constructor injection.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface
 */
protected $_localeCurrency

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
)
{
    $this->_localecurrency = $localeCurrency;
}
```

Now you can use below code in your function to get currency symbol.

```
$this->_localecurrency->getCurrency($currencycode)->getSymbol();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the symbol:

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_Symbol = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($_code);
echo $_Symbol->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. $_code is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using object manager try with currency interface

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
    )
{
    $this->localecurrency = $localeCurrency;
}
$this->localecurrency->getCurrency($currencycode)->getSymbol();
```

For full code please refer here http://webhintsexplorer.com/magento-2-get-currency-symbol-by-code/

Answer (score 0):

It also works like this:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager =$objectManager>get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currency = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');

$store = $storeManager->getStore();

print_r($store->getWebsite()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol());
```