# How to get currency Symbol in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, currency, multicurrency, object-manager

I want currency Symbol using currency code in magento 2. so any one help me?

I have tried below code but I got error  `Class Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFact‌​ory` does not exist

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$currencyManager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFac‌​tory')->create()->ge‌​tResource(); 
echo $currencySymbol = $currencyManager->getCurrencyCodeFromToCurrency($_code);
```

Comment: I want currency Symbol using currency code in magento 2. so any one help me?

Comment: @Marius This boy only wants currency code that's why voted this  for reopen, may be some one can easily answer this question

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala if you say you can answer this I will reopen it, but this looks like a poorly  asked question to me.

Comment: @SusantaKumarDas here is your answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130102/magento-2-get-currency-symbol-from-currency-code/149147

Comment: <?php $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $currencyManager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->getResource(); 
                    echo $currencySymbol = $currencyManager->getCurrencyCodeFromToCurrency($_code); ?>  I am use this code but not working.

Comment: @Marius Yes this is poorly asked question , but I can tell one of my friends to give answer , who has this answer

Comment: @SusantaKumarDas please add this code in your question and also tell us in which file and place  you are using this code

Comment: @SusantaKumarDas I have edited your question, please check it is correct?

Comment: Using objectmanager is not proper way to get currency code, $currencyManager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->create(); 
      echo $currencySymbol = $currencyManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
class Customclass{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $currencySymbol;
    protected $localeCurrency;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currencySymbol,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->currencySymbol = $currencySymbol;
        $this->localecurrency = $localeCurrency;
    }

    public function getStoreCurrency(){
        $currencycode = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        return $this->localecurrency->getCurrency($currencycode)->getSymbol();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are this serious? All of that just to get a "$"/"R$"/"€"/etc symbol?

Comment: Maybe a PR with a helper to do that could be good, let's try..

Answer (score 0):

There is no method available of

you can use like this to get currency symbol.

```
 $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $currencyManager = $om->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency'); 
 echo $currencyManager->getCurrencySymbol();
```

or you set currency symbol using below code.

```
$priceHelper = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
echo $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the symbol:

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_Symbol = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($_code);
echo $_Symbol->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Comment: Have you try below solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To get Currency symbol use the following code into your phtml or your block.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency')->getCurrencySymbol();
```

or replace get with create sometime I have faced this issue according to the location of code like block, controller, Model or phtml.

```
$currencysymbol = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency')->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is the code**

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
echo $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($_code)->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Currency Symbol :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

$price =  1000; //Your Price

$formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
```