# Format price value in knockout template

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

In Magento 2's checkout summary I managed to add price values to each "item in cart":

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.price_incl_tax"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $parent.row_total_incl_tax"></span>
```

Unfortunately those are plain numbers and a debug shows that $parent does not contain pre-formatted price values:

```
{
  "item_id":134,
  "price":420.17,
  "base_price":420.17,
  "qty":1,
  "row_total":420.17,
  "base_row_total":420.17,
  "row_total_with_discount":0,
  "tax_amount":79.83,
  "base_tax_amount":79.83,
  "tax_percent":19,
  "discount_amount":0,
  "base_discount_amount":0,
  "discount_percent":0,
  "price_incl_tax":500,
  "base_price_incl_tax":500,
  "row_total_incl_tax":500,
  "base_row_total_incl_tax":500,
  "options":"[]",
  "weee_tax_applied_amount":null,
  "weee_tax_applied":null,
  "name":"My awesome product"
}
```

How could I format these as actual price values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details': {
                'VendorName_ModuleName/js/mixin/details-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/details-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function(
    quote,
    priceUtils
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            /**
             * @param {*} price
             * @return {*|String}
             */
            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now use :

```
<span data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice($parent.price_incl_tax)"></span>
<span data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice($parent.row_total_incl_tax)"></span>
```

Clear cache and deploy static content.

Comment: This answer is cleaner than mine.

Comment: will this also include the currency symbol?

Comment: @BenCrook yes .

Comment: @SohelRana but what about if I wanted to use in product detail page ?

Comment: I've got this error: `ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return getFormattedPrice(price_incl_tax) }" Message: getFormattedPrice is not defined`

Comment: @krybbio I've received that error, and it was because I was in a KO for loop; I've prepended the function with "$parent", so it becomes ````$parent.getFormattedPrice(12.3456)````

Answer (score 1):

To convert your number to a string you can use `.toString()`:

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.price_incl_tax.toString()"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $parent.row_total_incl_tax.toString()"></span>
```

You'll also need to get the currency symbol (unless you're happy to hardcode it), there are some questions about that below:

- [Magento 2 Get Currency Symbol from Currency Code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130102/magento-2-get-currency-symbol-from-currency-code)
- [Magento 2 Get Currency Symbol from Currency Code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130102/magento-2-get-currency-symbol-from-currency-code)
- [How to get currency Symbol in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149152/how-to-get-currency-symbol-in-magento-2)